# how to get value of a node in nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have this

```
1.9.3-p286 :073 > doc.css("tr[class~=strong]").children[3].children
 => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fee5e077e98 name="a" attributes=[#
      <Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fee5e077dd0 name="href" 
      value="http://somelink">]>]
```

Sample html:

```
<tr class='strong bf highbeam'>
  <td>December 6th</td>
  <td>Foo</td>
  <td><a href='http://somelink' title='bar'>December 6th 2012 Episode</a></td>
  <td><a href='http://somelink/#disqus_thread'></a></td>
</tr>
```

How can I fetch the value `http://somelink` at this point?

Comment: It really helps if you show a sample of the HTML, not the output of the IRB step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `children`, refine your css selector until you get the element you want:

```
doc.at('tr.strong a')[:href]
```